# Why is wireless internet on Ubuntu so slow?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

For some reason, whenever I connect to the internet by wireless using Ubuntu 12.04 (kernel version 3.8.0-29), webpages often take up to one minute or more to load and often do not load at all. I then have to disconnect and reconnect, and sometimes this doesn't work. Does anyone else have this problem? Is there a solution to it?

Comment: You have a problemwith your driver. What is your card (Vendor and Product IDs, please) and driver?

Comment: It is a Realtek RTL8188CE Wireless Lan.

Comment: Driver? You can find it by looking at the output of sudo lshw -C network

Comment: You may try the solution given on this very same site, here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/342076/step-by-step-ubuntu-12-04-install-of-realtek-rtl8188ce-driver

Answer (score 1):

So I downloaded the driver from Realtek for Linux Kernel v2.6++ website, debugged it(there were so errors int the sw.c files for the various interface folders and the pci.h files using the macro __devinit which gcc objected to even though it was defined), used the **make** command after extracting the tar.bz2 file and *voilà*! It works and the problem is solved. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

You may have Network Manager installed. So you could try with Wicd, as it works better for me.Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager*

sudo apt-get install wicd  

sudo restart
```

Then, enter the password and go on. Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: What does "network connection manager that can manage wireless and wired interfaces"(quoted from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd)) have to do with the speed of wifi?

Comment: I had issues with this program. My wireless connection was connected and disconnected randomly. Wicd solved my problem.

Comment: network connection manager manages wireless connection (connects/disconnects), it does nothing more than just connecting and disconnecting, so "My wireless connection was connected and disconnected randomly" may be because of that program but if that manager successfully connects to a network(it does its job) and the problem is the speed, it is more likely a driver problem.

Comment: Just keep in mind if you don't solve the issue. If you try, won't lose anything.

Comment: Tried that Manolo Salsas, and it didn't help. As others have pointed out, it was a faulty driver that was causing the problem. Your problem had similar symptoms but a different cause. I didn't have network manager anyway.